# Automatized restoring of display settings

Tags: resolution, display

I have two displays: my laptop's main monitor, running at resolution 1366x786 and second, external, running at resolution 1920x1080.

My default display setting is to use both monitors at these resolutions, but the secondary monitor is at the left side of the primary monitor (instead of default right side).

But some programs, especially games, change the resolution and usually use only one display (the second one is being disabled). After exiting such application it usually is restoring only the resolution of the first display, and the second one is disabled.

After that I need to re-enable my default settings and do a lot of clicking in the settings panel.

So my questions are:

1. Where can I find or how can I save my default two-display setting?
2. How can I automatize the restoration of my default settings? (maybe some bash script) The one-click solution would be great.

I use Mint 16 and nvidia graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out https://github.com/wertarbyte/autorandr which is smart enough to detect what's connected, but it also allows you to create profiles that can be retrieved using keyboard shortcuts. So if a program messes with your displays, you can then run autorandr with an associated profile and it will properly reconfigure.

Comment: It throws some errors, unfortunately...